# c# Tridimensional array into 3 single dimension arrays

Tags: c#, .net, multidimensional-array

Maybe it's a basic question, but I am not reaching the correct method to get the value of a tridimensional array item or get three separate single arrays from a tridimensional array.

For a given `float[,,] array3d` as : {[a0,b0,c0], [a1,b1,c1], [a2,b2,c2]...}
I need to get three arrays as: a{a0 , a1, a2}, b{b1, b2, b3} and c{c1, c2, c3}

If it's not a direct method, I am trying to access to each element as array3d[row, column], but it's not working...

```
            a = new float[length];
            b = new float[length];
            c = new float[length];

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                a[i] = array3d[i, 0]; //how can I access to that row, column element?
                b[i] = array3d[i, 1];
                c[i] = array3d[i, 2];
            }
```

Comment: Your `array3d` requires 3 indices. But I don't understand your question, can you give an example?

Comment: _get three separate single arrays from a tridimensional array._ Not possible.

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă, the example is the above, for example, how do you get the value of a0? float a0 = ...;

Comment: It seems from your example that `array3d` is actually a 2-dimensional array. Can you show the code that creates `array3d`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 3D you have to provide 3 indexes to access a particular element. If i understand your question the following code should work for you

```
int[, ,] array3d = new int[2, 2, 3]{
            { { 1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} },
            { { 7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12} }
        };
List<float> a = new List<float>;
List<float> b = new List<float>;
List<float> c = new List<float>;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        a.Add(array3d[i, j, 0]);
        b.Add(array3d[i, j, 1]);
        c.Add(array3d[i, j, 2]);
    }
}
```